# How to style a specific react-google-login component

Tags: css, reactjs, react-component

So, I am trying to style a GoogleButton from the [react-google-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) package, with external CSS. More specifically, I am trying to center it. However, try as I might, it won't center. I have tried:

1. `align-content`
2. `align-items`
3. `align-self`
4. `box-align`

All with no avail. How would I possibly style the component, considering it has a className of `signInButton`?

Here is a depiction of my current situation:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the left/right margins to `auto`?

Comment: Try adding style style={{width: "50%"}}

Comment: @jo_va Tried both `left` and `margin-left` (and their right counterparts), but with no avail

Comment: @HemadriDasari tried this as well right now, nothing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.signInButton {
  float:none;
  position:static;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
  width:max-content;
}
```

if it will not work then you should provide list of used CSS properties for that button.

Note that these two

```
  float:none;
  position:static;
```

are optional, I put them there to override potential values that may interfere with alignment.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure parent element is a flexbox.

```
.parent { 
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center; 
}
```

You can wrap the component into a new div and style it if you don't want to affect parent element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `renderProps` to create a custom button:

```
render={renderProps => (
      <button onClick={renderProps.onClick} disabled={renderProps.disabled}>This is my custom Google button</button>
    )}
```

Check out this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login#google-button-without-styling-or-custom-button).